# Overriding main function in Leonardo

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I've trying to write my code in plain C++ dropping out the Arduino's IDE. Although I've succeed in compiling the code, whenever I try to upload it to the board it doesn't run, seems that it stucks at some unknown point.

After that, everytime I try to upload a new code to the board it stops responding and avrdude throws this message:

```
$ ino upload -m leonardo -p /dev/ttyACM1
/dev/ttyACM1 doesn't exist. Is Arduino connected?
```

It doesn't matter if I unplug and then plug again the board, that message is still showing up.

In order to restart the board, I open the Arduino IDE and then I upload any sketch, then the board comes to live again.

The first time I tried overriding the main() function and the program didn't run I thought it was the tool I was using at that moment, *arduino.mk*, the one that was doing something strange.

Then I tried the *ino* tool, but the result was the same.

I don't think *avrdude* is failing because it actually uploads the .hex to the board.

My original main() code was:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

const int LED_PIN = 13;

int main(void)
{
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

    while (1)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        delay(900);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I tried to mimic the one that comes with Arduino:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

const int LED_PIN = 13;

int main(void)
{
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

#if defined (USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif  

    while (1)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        delay(900);

        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sadly, with both codes the board gets stucked at some point.

While I figure out how to solve this issue I've been exercising this solution inside a sketch:

```
const int LED_PIN = 13;

void setup() {                
}

void loop() {
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);     

    while (1)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        delay(900);
    }
}
```

Any ideas that led me to a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Solved!**

It was a (big) silly mistake of my own. I overloocked the init() function right after entering the main() function. I'm shure it initializes the hardware and the entire system, so my board stucks when I skipped it.

So my code now looks like this:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

const int LED_PIN = 13;

int main(void)
{
    init();


#if defined (USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif  

    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

    while (1)
    {

        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        delay(900);

        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

BTW, the mix: Arduino + Vim + ino, rocks! Now I can do whatever I want from the console :)